# After submitting email form, I want to stay on the same page and message like success to apear

Tags: php, html

I want after submitting the email information, to stay on the same page, instead of redirecting me to new one.

THis is my html code:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="formaa" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <input name="name" placeholder="Name" id="aa">
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="aa">      
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>      
    <input name="human" placeholder="2+2=" id="ab">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From: PappuLighting'; 
$to = 'v.karageorgiev@pappu-lighting.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$human = $_POST['human'];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You need javascript / ajax to do that.

Comment: Instead of form submit, use jquery `ajax()`

Comment: Also you can  put the both the code in same file by Adding php code to top of the file and form at bottom. In form put action attribute empty

Comment: As your contact page is a standard HTML page ( unless you have set the .htaccess file in such a way as to emulate an html page ) then you would need javascript. If the page itself was PHP you could send the form to the same page and then you would have access to the messages after the form was submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this ==> put the php and html code in same file and `action=""`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From: PappuLighting'; 
$to = 'v.karageorgiev@pappu-lighting.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$human = $_POST['human'];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
$messageSuccess =  '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
$messageerror =  '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
$messageerror = '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
}
?>

    <?php  
    if(isset($messageSuccess))
    echo $messageSuccess;

   else if(isset($messageSuccess))
    echo $messageerror;
    ?>

<form method="post" action="" id="formaa" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <input name="name" placeholder="Name" id="aa">
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="aa">      
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>      
    <input name="human" placeholder="2+2=" id="ab">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Its happening, but http://pappu-lighting.com/Contact/LAST.html look when you submit what happens.

Comment: @ValeriKarageorgiev your html is incorrect. put error message above opening `<form>` and provide the better style(css) for that

Comment: I am not sure how to do that... What do you mean by error massage?

Comment: change position of your error/success message put it after <h3> above <form> tag

Comment: Ok may be I am blind, but i dont see having any error/success code in HTML to put above <form>

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax calls by using one frameworks that makes ajax simple like jQuery or AngularJS. in that case in the server side you should create REST APi endpoint to send email.